# An issue about pysam installation

Tags: python, linux, conda, samtools, pysam

It's linux, using conda to install pysam, and `pip install pysam` keep failing.
After successful installed pysam, 
pysam shows in `conda list` and appears in `anaconda2/pkgs/`
but when `import pysam` in python 2.7.12, it failed by `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pysam`

PLS help.